# Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details Warning?

Tags: java

I wrote this code where when the software starts it takes data from a database (MYSQL control center) and bring them to a table. But when I compile this code 2 errors occurs.

```
Note: C:\Users\Commander Shepard\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Furniture Management System\src\furnituremanagementsystem\employee.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

My Code:

```
public class employee extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Creates new form employee
    public employee() {
        initComponents();           

        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        datelabel.setText(formatter.format(now));

        try {
            Statement s = DB.getConnection().createStatement();
            DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            dtm.setRowCount(0);
            ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * from Employee");
            while (r.next()) {
                Vector v = new Vector();
                v.add(r.getString(1));
                v.add(r.getString(2));
                v.add(r.getString(3));
                v.add(r.getString(4));
                v.add(r.getString(5));
                v.add(r.getString(6));
                v.add(r.getString(7));
                v.add(r.getString(8));
                v.add(r.getString(9));
                v.add(r.getString(10));
                v.add(r.getString(11));
                v.add(r.getString(12));
                v.add(r.getString(13));
                v.add(r.getString(14));

                dtm.addRow(v);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ...
}
```

The thing didn't actually affect the program, it's working properly, but I want to know if this is going to be a problem in the future and whether I should do something about this.

Comment: Yes - you should recompile with -Xlint:unchecked and review the more detailed warning. (You're using the raw `Vector` type, instead of `Vector<String>`, for one thing. But the important thing is simply to follow the compiler's advice.)

Comment: Well how are you compiling? You just add the `-Xlint:unchecked` flag to the compiler...

Comment: Well I'm doing this by netbeans so I just click the compile button and that's it. So how do I edit the way it compiles?

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, but it looks like it uses Ant to specify build details, so edit the build.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

That happens when you use generic references. You don't really need to take the warning into consideration, but if you want to see what it is you should compile again with the new argument:

javac programname.java argument

But using generics in Java has many problems as it was added quite late and with all the backward compatibility issues, yeah, we don't need to get into that.

Answer (score 0):

Do as it says:

> Note: Recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked` for details.

For example, with Gradle:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {         
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

(Back then) with NetBeans, that would have been  "Additional Compiler Options".

Answer (score -2):

You used the raw form of the [`Vector` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).  It is a generic class.  Since you're adding `String`s, try

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
```

Comment: But arraylists doesn't work with Table Models as Vector does.

Comment: Didn't catch that it was for the `DefaultTableModel`.  Taking the `ArrayList` part out...